# Using arrays in nlapiCreateFile

Tags: netsuite

I have been using `nlapiCreateFile()` and `nlapiSubmitFile()` to create a CSV file from an array, and have run in to two problems I cant seem to figure out.  When the CSV file is saved excel prints out each element of the array in to its own cell like it should but it prints it all on the same row (1a, 1b, 1c, 1d.. etc) I would rather have the array print downwards in the same column rather then row(1a, 2a, 3a, 4a... etc) if possible.  But im not sure how to approach this.

```
var file1 = nlapiCreateFile('names.csv', 'CSV', names);
file1.setFolder(295767);
nlapiSubmitFile(file1);
```

The second thing I cant seem to figure out, if I wanted to print a second array in the same file, how would I approach that?  For example the `names` array in the first columns and another array in the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an Array for the third parameter of `nlapiCreateFile()`, try using a string that uses the `,` for column delimiters, and `\n` as a line separator.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is rather old, but for those who are trying to figure this out, you want to use the join method:

```
var file1 = nlapiCreateFile('names.csv', 'CSV', names.join("\n"));
file1.setFolder(295767);
nlapiSubmitFile(file1);
```

This returns a string of the array, with the elements separated by the provided parameter. In this case, we want one column with all of the elements so we choose \n or new line.

For appending to a file, I believe you will have to load the record again, which will return and nlobjFile Object https://debugger.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3066995.html#bridgehead_N3067099

Then you can add to it, and then submit again.